# Custom scrollbars for <vaadin-combo-box> , impossible?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-core-elements

I'm using vaadin-combo-box and I have a problem. I have no clue how to customize look and feel of scrollbars for the dropdown. I read about styling parts and I know how to do it but this seems to be impossible. Cant figure out the way to select #scroller element because it has been design not to be a "part" to style. However that is the only way I can think of to apply custom style to dropdown scrollbars. How can that be accomplished?

Thanks in advance for help.

**#Update**

Turns out that as of today there is no way of having customized styling on scrollbars for **vaadin-combo-box** component. Element responsible for scrolling resides inside contents **shadow DOM** and is inaccessible from outside nor its going to inherit style implemented on the parent part `[part="content"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown part is called `vaadin-combo-box-overlay`, see: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/html-api/elements/Vaadin.ComboBoxOverlayElement And it is available for styling.

This allows to style the dropdown to some extent, but there is additional shadow root, that prevents to apply e.g. `::-webkit-scrollbar` styles on `#scroller` element.

So the last option would be to make a copy of the `vaadin-combo-box` html file in right place in `frontend` directory. It happens so that that file will be used instead of the one coming from webjar. Then you can edit that html file directly. Of course this means that if there are changes in future versions of vaadin-combo-box, you need to copy again, re-apply changes

Comment: I refined my answer as well

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes, after contacting vaadin team seems like that would be the only way to style scrollbars... too bad they haven't thought about it...